# Wav file write and play multiplie time

Tags: c, wav, pcm

I have a requirement, where I need to write a wav (with pcma data) file multiple times.

Say I have a file **audio-g711a.wav**. I want to write it to a new file say **audio-g711a-out.wav** 2 times. When I play  **audio-g711a-out.wav** , it should play twice the longer duration than that of original file.

I did write using below code. However it plays for exactly same duration as that of original file (I was expecting it to play double the duration).

Code is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int g_count = 0;

void init_config(int argc,char **argv);
void rewrite_file(int count);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    init_config(argc, argv);
    printf("Count = %d\n", g_count);
    rewrite_file(g_count);
    return 0;
}

void rewrite_file(int count)
{
    int index;
    char arr[101];
    FILE *fd_in;
    FILE *fd_out;
    size_t len;
    unsigned long chunk_size;

    index = 0;
    fd_in = fopen("./audio-g711a.wav", "r");
    fd_out = fopen("./audio-g711a-out.wav", "w+");

rw_again:    
    index++;
    len = fread(arr, 1, 100, fd_in);
    while(len == 100)
    {
        fwrite(arr, 1, 100, fd_out);
        len = fread(arr, 1, 100, fd_in);
    }
    fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);
    if(count > index)
    {
        printf("Completed %d round of operation of %d total rounds.\n", index, count);
        fclose(fd_in);
        fd_in = fopen("./audio-g711a.wav", "r");
        goto rw_again;
    }

    return;
}

void init_config(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "v:n:N:X")) != -1)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
            {
                g_count = atoi(optarg);
            }
            break;

            default:
            break;

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

To execute this, one can execute like ./a.out -n 2

After some R&D, I realized wav files have some sort of header. When I write second time, I am writing the header again. That may cause the file not to play further. I stopped writing the header part (44 bytes) while writing second time. This did not solve the issue.

Can somebody please guide me how can I achieve writing a wav file for at least 2 times.

**Update**
The working code is as given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int g_count = 0;

void init_config(int argc,char **argv);
void rewrite_file(int count);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    init_config(argc, argv);
    printf("Count = %d\n", g_count);
    rewrite_file(g_count);
    return 0;
}

void rewrite_file(int count)
{
    int index;
    char arr[101];
    FILE *fd_in;
    FILE *fd_out;
    size_t len;
    unsigned short data_index = 0;
    index = 0;
    fd_in = fopen("./audio-g711a.wav", "r");
    fd_out = fopen("./audio-g711a-out.wav", "w+");

    // copy header
    len = fread(arr, 1, 40, fd_in);
    fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);

    if( strncmp("data", (arr+36), 4) == 0 )
    {
        data_index = 40;
    }
    else
    {
        len = fread(arr, 1, 14, fd_in);
        fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);

        if( strncmp("data", (arr+10), 4) == 0 )
        {
            data_index = 54;
        }
    }


    // update header
    uint32_t dl;
    fseek(fd_in, data_index, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(fd_out, data_index, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&dl, sizeof(dl), 1, fd_in);
    dl *= count;
    fwrite(&dl, sizeof(dl), 1, fd_out);

    // copy data
rw_again:
    index++;
    fseek(fd_in, (4 + data_index), SEEK_SET);
    len = fread(arr, 1, 100, fd_in);
    while(len > 0)
    {
        fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);
        len = fread(arr, 1, 100, fd_in);
    }
    fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);
    if(count > index)
    {
        printf("Completed %d round of operation of %d total rounds.\n", index, count);
        fclose(fd_in);
        fd_in = fopen("./audio-g711a.wav", "r");
        goto rw_again;
    }

    fclose(fd_in);
    fclose(fd_out);

    return;
}
void init_config(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "v:n:N:X")) != -1)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
            {
                g_count = atoi(optarg);
            }
            break;

            default:
            break;

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Look up the format of the header. You need to change some parts of the header.

Comment: I saw the format here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29676/CWave-A-Simple-C-Class-to-Manipulate-WAV-Files. But do not understand what I need to do...

Comment: The header is only 36 bytes. The following 8 bytes belong to the first data chunk.

Comment: You also need to increase the chunksize value (offset 4-7 in the header) with the appropriate value.

Comment: Looks chunk size is little endian. For me in original file bytes from 4th to 7th are 0x32 0x40 0x3 0x0. Since I am going to write the file two times, shall I double it.

Comment: You need to read the chunksize (file offset: 40) from the input file, double the chunkzise and write it to the output file (same offset).

Comment: The chunksize are the four bytes after the "data" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wav file has a header and a data section:

```
[HEADER][DATA]
```

A simple copy, as you do, produces the following file format:

```
[HEADER][DATA][HEADER][DATA]
```

What you need is:

```
[HEADER][DATADATA]
     ^
     |
     +--- chunksize at offset 40 updated
```

Here is a quick hack:

```
void rewrite_file(int count)
{
    int index;
    char arr[101];
    FILE *fd_in;
    FILE *fd_out;
    size_t len;
    unsigned long chunk_size;

    index = 0;
    fd_in = fopen("./audio-g711a.wav", "r");
    fd_out = fopen("./audio-g711a-out.wav", "w+");

    // copy header
    len = fread(arr, 1, 40, fd_in);
    fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);

    // update header
    uint32_t dl;
    fseek(fd_in, 40, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(fd_out, 40, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&dl, sizeof(dl), 1, fd_in);
    dl *= count;
    fwrite(&dl, sizeof(dl), 1, fd_out);

    // copy data
rw_again:
    index++;
    fseek(fd_in, 44, SEEK_SET);
    len = fread(arr, 1, 100, fd_in);
    while(len > 0)
    {
        fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);
        len = fread(arr, 1, 100, fd_in);
    }
    fwrite(arr, 1, len, fd_out);
    if(count > index)
    {
        printf("Completed %d round of operation of %d total rounds.\n", index, count);
        fclose(fd_in);
        fd_in = fopen("./audio-g711a.wav", "r");        
        goto rw_again;
    }

    fclose(fd_in);
    fclose(fd_out);

    return;
}
```

**Update:**

If the wav file contains a 'fact' chunk (non-PCM formats), then data chunk size offset is not 40, but 54 for example. So it better to search the 'data'-tag to calculate the data chunk offset than to use the 40 as a magic number.

Comment: Tried this code as it is. If I play using avplay I get error. [wav @ 0x7f1b00004f80] no 'data' tag found
audio-g711a-out.wav: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: @user1861447 Hm, works with my test file. Can you provide your file?

Comment: Kindly share your email id. Or is there any way I can send file through stack overflow.

Comment: @user1861447 The chunksize offset is 54 in your file, change 40 to 54 and 44 to 58.

Comment: Please see the updated code in my original post. Am I correct in assuming data tag is present either at 36th index or at 50th index. Is it possible data tag can come at different index as well.

Comment: @user1861447 I am not 100% sure about the indexes, I guess the best is to search for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the "data" part of the "data" subchunk.

Read the total chunksize (offset 4).

Read the data subchunk size (offset 40).

Those two values should be increased by the subchunk size (maybe -4 if the 4 byte for the size is included in the subchunk size value).

The data part of the data subchunk (starting at offset 44) should be doubled (written twice).